# Environment setup issue while running KYLIN_HOME/bin/check-env.sh

Tags: apache, hadoop2, kylin

While checking the environment setup of Kylin2.1.0, it returns the following "Please make sure the user has the privilege to run hadoop shell"

Versions of tools used

```
Hadoop: 2.7
Hive:  2.0.0
HBase: hbase-1.2.4
JDK: 1.7


root@ubuntu:~/kylin-2.1.0/bin$ ./check-env.sh
Retrieving hadoop conf dir...
KYLIN_HOME is set to /home/user/kylin-2.1.0
Please make sure the user has the privilege to run hadoop shell
```

Comment: Finally I a got  the solution for above issue. I set a path variable for " vi.bashrc " ie, " export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$HADOOP_HOME/sbin:$HADOOP_HOME/bin:$HIVE_HOME/bin:$HBASE_HOME/bin:$KYLIN_HOME/bin$PATH "

Comment: Once the environment has been setup, just run this command ./check-env.sh from your kylin bin directory. If still the problem remains you need to reboot your system.